# data.table assigning with `sapply` in a merge

Tags: r, data.table

I have some `data.tables` like so:

```
x <- data.table(id=rep(1:3, 2), a=1:6)
y <- data.table(id=1:3, b=2:4)
```

I can merge them like this:

```
setkey(x, id)
setkey(y, id)
x[y]
   id a b
1:  1 1 2
2:  1 4 2
3:  2 2 3
4:  2 5 3
5:  3 3 4
6:  3 6 4
```

Now, I want to create a new column in `x` based off `a` and `b` which is the sum of `a` and `b`.
I can do this with:

```
x[y, val:=a + b]
```

**However, now suppose for some reason that the '+' operator is not vectorised. How can I store a row-wise calculation into `x` where `x[y]` is needed for the calculation? Also, assume I cannot use `mapply`** (because for my actual problem, `mapply` is not suited to the function).

I'm trying to use `sapply` like so to add in a row-wise manner:

```
x[y, sapply(1:nrow(x), function (i) a[i] + b[i])]
```

However this returns the incorrect result:

```
    id V1
 1:  1  3
 2:  1 NA
 3:  1 NA
 4:  1 NA
 5:  1 NA
 6:  1 NA
 7:  2  5
 8:  2 NA
 9:  2 NA
10:  2 NA
11:  2 NA
12:  2 NA
13:  3  7
14:  3 NA
15:  3 NA
16:  3 NA
17:  3 NA
18:  3 NA
```

If I do this it works:

```
x[y][, sapply(1:nrow(x), function (i) a[i] + b[i])]
# [1] 3 6 5 8 7 10
```

**BUT** when I try and assign this to a column in `x`, it is not stored (makes sense because it looks like I'm trying to save the new column into `x[y]`).

```
x[y][, val:=sapply(1:nrow(x), function (i) a[i] + b[i])]
```

Is there any way to do the above but save the output into `x[, val]`?
Is this how I am supposed to do it, or is there a more `data.table`-y way?

```
x[, val:=x[y][, sapply(1:nrow(x), function (i) a[i] + b[i])]]
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you give a better example of the function you want to vectorize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing `by-without-by` without knowing it, (see below for the description from the help)

> Advanced: Aggregation for a subset of known groups is particularly
>   efficient when passing those groups in i. When i is a data.table,
>   DT[i,j] evaluates j for each row of i. We call this by without by or
>   grouping by i. Hence, the self join DT[data.table(unique(colA)),j] is
>   identical to DT[,j,by=colA].

This means that `j` is evaluated for each row of `i` (cylcing through `y` one row at a time -- so that if you run `sapply(1:nrow(x),...)` in `j` it will create a vector of length `nrow(x)` each time, when this is not what you want.

So your second option is definitely a valid approach (as it is one of the recommended approaches for doing this)

Otherwise you could use `.N` (*When grouping by i, .N is the number of rows in x matched to, for each row of i*)  not `nrow(x)`, but you will have to think about the length of your objects and how your function is to be vectorized.

Take this as an example

```
x[y, {browser(); a+b}]
Called from: `[.data.table`(x, y, {
    browser()
    a + b
})
Browse[1]> a
[1] 1 4
Browse[1]> b
[1] 2
Browse[1]> .N
[1] 2
```

`a` has length two, because value of the key  matches with 2 rows from x. `b` only has length `1` because it only has length 1 in `y`.

I think the best approach is to correctly Vectorize your function (which is hard to give advice upon without more of an example)

another approach would be to replicate `b` to the length of `a` eg

```
 x[y, val := {
 bl <- rep_len(b, .N)
 sapply(seq_len(.N), function(i) a[i] + bl[i])}]
x
   id a val
1:  1 1   3
2:  1 4   6
3:  2 2   5
4:  2 5   8
5:  3 3   7
6:  3 6  10
```

or if you know that `y` has unique rows for each value of `id`, then you don't need to try and index any columns from it.

```
x[y, val2 := sapply(seq_len(.N), function(i) a[i] + b)]
# an alternative would be to use sapply on a (avoid creating another vector)
x[y, val3 := sapply(a, function(ai) ai + b)]
x
#    id a val val2 val3
# 1:  1 1   3    3    3
# 2:  1 4   6    6    6
# 3:  2 2   5    5    5
# 4:  2 5   8    8    8
# 5:  3 3   7    7    7
# 6:  3 6  10   10   10
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation on differing lengths of `a` and `b`. I asked because my function really is not vectorizable without using `sapply` as I have in the question (it *almost* fit `mapply`, but one of the arguments to the function is `list(a[i], b[i])` and I don't want to generate the entire list of lists that I would need to feed this to `mapply`).

Comment: Although I'm not sure I understand the `by-without-by` documentation and how it is relevant to my question, unless I am doing `by=1:nrow(x)`?

Comment: Yes `1:nrow(x)` is not what you want  if it is within the same `[]` call as the `i` join that is implementing by-without-by. Moving to a separate `[]` call is one way to go. See my edit.